# Uploading videos to Onedrive?

Tags: video, nokia-lumia-920, onedrive, uploading

The Onedrive application and the Photos application only allow me to share photos to Onedrive.

The only options that appear in a video file’s sharing menu are for email accounts. The video files I have recorded, of course, are just above the transfer limit for my email providers.

What other alternatives do I have for transferring videos from my Windows Phone 8 device?

Comment: On my Nokia 920 I have a save to Skydrive option...

Comment: You can also try Tap+Send to another device that supports NFC.

Comment: My HTC Windows 8X also has a save to SkyDrive option that does indeed work.

Answer (score 2):

My 920 doesn't have options for Good quality etc, just upload and don't upload. The work around is plug your phone into your pc via usb, find the phone in my computer, it should show up as a drive. Open the video folder and cut and paste the video into the photos folder. 
Go to the phone now. Open photos, albums, other pictures and the video should be there. Click on the video and Save to OneDrive should be in the options menu bottom right.

Answer (score 1):

Photos -> Camera roll. Slide the menu bar at the bottom. Select the option OneDrive settings. It has separate settings for Photos and Videos.

In my phone for videos by default "Don't Upload" was selected. Change the setting to Good quality or best quality.

Now go back to camera roll and select the video and slide the menu bar from the bottom. You should see "Save to OneDrive" option.